# React fetch, async, i never know when it goes from undefined to ok

Tags: reactjs, async-await, fetch, state, use-effect

I'm pretty frustrated because I don't know when I for sure set a State and then I can work with that state on other sections of my App.
What I am trying to do is get 40 photos from an API, and set them to a state called photoList.

And then setting only 10 of these to be visible and render them. After that I want to do pagination so I can change states and show the 10-20 photos, 20-30 photos, etc.

```
function PhotoList() {
  
  const [photoList, setPhotoList] = useState([]);
  const [visiblePhotos, setVisiblePhotos] = useState([]);
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("hello");

  useEffect(() => {
    requestPhotos();
    loadFirstTen();
  }
  , []);


  const loadFirstTen = () =>{

    let photos = [];
    
    for(let i=0; i<10; i++){
      photos.push(photoList[i]);
    }
    setVisiblePhotos(photos);

  }

  async function requestPhotos(){

    const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos"
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const json = await response.json();

    let Photos = [];

    for(let i=0; i<40; i++){
      Photos.push(json[i]);
    }

    setPhotoList(Photos);
    
  }

  const listItems = visiblePhotos.map((photo) => 
    <div className="bottom-40 display-inline" >
      <MediaCard title={photo.title} image={photo.url} className="display-inline"/>
    </div>
  );
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{title}</h1>
      {listItems}
    </div>
  );
}

export default PhotoList;
```

I really do not understand. If i put everything inside the requestPhotos function, it works, and I can set the first ten photos. But if I do it outside that function, after I have already set the complete list of photos, it says "undefined".

I am trying to separate things and do separate functions so it does not all go on one go, but I really do not understand what is going on. Plus, I have no certainty that if I call other functions for example after someone clicks on the page 2 button, that photoList will effectively have the 40 photos, and that I will not get an undefined message.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure to load `firstTen` and more only once your `photoList` is filled after the API Call. I would suggest to manage and call your first and next photos conditionally within the `useEffect()`.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-phoebe-1bhsr?file=/src/App.tsx:923-1104) you can have a look on a working sample App.

Just for demonstration purposes I replaced your `MediaCard` with a `<p>`.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function PhotoList() {
  const [photoList, setPhotoList] = useState([]);
  const [visiblePhotos, setVisiblePhotos] = useState([]);
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("hello");
  const [page, setPage] = useState(0);

  async function requestPhotos() {
    const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos";
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const json = await response.json();

    let Photos = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
      Photos.push(json[i]);
    }

    setPhotoList(Photos);
  }

  const loadFirstTen = () => {
    let photos = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      photos.push(photoList[i]);
    }
    setVisiblePhotos(photos);
    setPage(1);
  };

  const loadNextTen = () => {
    let photos = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      photos.push(photoList[i + 10 * page - 10]);
    }
    setVisiblePhotos(photos);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    !photoList.length && page < 2 && requestPhotos();
    photoList.length && page < 2 && loadFirstTen();
    page > 1 && loadNextTen();
  }, [photoList, page]);

  const listItems = visiblePhotos.map((photo) => (
    <div className="bottom-40 display-inline">
      <p title={photo.title} image={photo.url} className="display-inline">
        {photo.title}
      </p>
    </div>
  ));

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{title}</h1>
      {listItems}
      <button onClick={() => setPage(page + 1)}>next</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default PhotoList;
```

Comment: Wow ok... so what that means is that if photoList is an empty array, it will requestPhotos... and if and only if photoList has been loaded, loadFirstTen will be executed.. that's what the code you wrote means?

Thanks for the reply by the way

Comment: exactly, when the component gets mounted the photoList is empty, so you run the first line in useEffect. when data is loaded from api you run the second line in useEffect. When you click the button, you run the third line in useEffect

Comment: @fhuneeus so does this answer your question? if not please let me know whats missing

Comment: I havent tried it yet, but I think it does

Comment: Hi @MWO, I just tried it, works like a charm. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are calling a async in a useEffect. Try to handle the promise with `.then` and `.catch` and set your photos in the `.then` function. This makes sure that the photos are fetched.